# AppBarLayout weight

Tags: android

I've got a problem.I have appBarLayout. Inside of it there are CollapsingToolbarLayout and LinearLayout. The problem is that CollapsingToolbarLayout has an imageView inside, and if the image is too large the LinearLayout is unvisible. I wish AppBarLayout had weight param, but unfortunately it doesn't.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/index"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hkdlf,kdg"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hkdlf,kdg,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"/>
    </LinearLayout>




</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Try changing layout_height in CollapsingToolbarLayout from "wrap_content" to "match_parent".